# Storyboards transition turns the device to portrait

Tags: user-interface, rotation, orientation, modalviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

In my app the storyboard controls 2 views. The main view and the flip-side view, both are in landscape but when I use the Modal function to transition between the to it turns my flipside view into portrait I use the code

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}`

to display the app in lanscape but it turns to portrait! My plist and the target summary both say lanscape.

All help would be appreciated!